# javascript is not working after update theme in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I update my theme using word press admin panel

so some of JavaScript on is breaking and some of pages are not displaying proper before that its working fine

So please Help me am new in word press

Thnaks

Comment: Please share the relevant code. The theme might have changed the classes,ids and DOM structure which might have broken the JS code.

Comment: Not enough information provided, 1. Is your wordpress version updated? 2. does your theme supported the current version of wordpress you are using? what error you are getting in your browser console log?

Comment: The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating   this error i facing

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be to take a look at the console log to determine what's throwing the error.
Then you could try to deactivate plugin by plugin until you find which plugin is breaking.
If you can't find it yet, add the following line to the wp-config.php file `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);`